# What software this log file comes from?

Tags: linux, log-files, ddos

From what software comes this logfile?
Please specify full name.

```
Internal IP
Threshold FlowsDiff 40 flows/s, Diff: 73 flows/s
Sum 26.962 flows/300s (89 flows/s), 32.162.000 packets/300s (107.206 packets/s), 1,198 GByte/300s (32 MBit/s)
External 87.98.238.221, 26.958 flows/300s (89 flows/s), 32.156.000 packets/300s (107.186 packets/s), 1,198 GByte/300s (32 MBit/s)
External 89.230.69.49, 2 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 2.000 packets/300s (6 packets/s), 0,000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
External 89.231.190.149, 1 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 3.000 packets/300s (10 packets/s), 0,000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
External 89.239.101.20, 1 flows/300s (0 flows/s), 1.000 packets/300s (3 packets/s), 0,000 GByte/300s (0 MBit/s)
```

Comment: From which file did you take it?

Comment: This looks a lot like homework?

Comment: It was not a homework, i just wanted to know the name of software to use to generate report like this one presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some sort of [Netflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflow) report.